# How to reset the text in kendo autocomplete after selection

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, autocomplete, kendo-ui-angular2

I'm using Kendo autocomplete with angular 4, I'm trying to clear the text in autocomplete box after selecting the value from popup.

```
<div class="example-wrapper">
  <kendo-autocomplete [data]="listItems" [value]="country" 
  [placeholder]="'e.g. Andorra'" (valueChange)="locationValueChange($event)">
  </kendo-autocomplete>

  <div *ngFor="let location of selectedValues; let i = index;">
                {{location}}
            </div>
</div>




public listItems: Array<string> = ["Albania", "Andorra", "Armenia", "Austria", "Azerbaijan"];


     public country: string = "Austria";

     public selectedValues: Array<string[]> = [];


     public locationValueChange(value: any): void {
       this.selectedValues.push(value);
       this.country='';
       console.log(this.country);
    }
```

Even when I'm setting value field to none. Its still having the data in box.
Please suggest any idea to achieve this.
[Plunker link of code](https://plnkr.co/edit/fd1axcd5niJPat0on8Zh?p=preview)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be achieved by utilizing the `reset` method of the auto-complete. ([Reference](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/dropdowns/api/AutoCompleteComponent/#toc-reset))

You can access to the auto-complete via the `ViewChild` decorator in your component, and the run the `reset` method every `valueChange`.

***.component.html**

```
 <kendo-autocomplete
      #autocomplete
      [data]="data"
      [value]="value" 
      (valueChange)="onValueChange($event)">
 </kendo-autocomplete>
```

***.component.ts**

```
 @Component({ ... })
 public class MyComponent {
      @ViewChild('autocomplete') autocomplete: AutoCompleteComponent;

      ...

      onValueChange(value: string){
          this.autocomplete.reset();
      }
}
```

I've also forked your [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/SzVOIg8uByCwHrIZ39tI?p=preview).